# Is Winterbash 2017 disabled for Internet Explorer users?

Tags: support, internet-explorer, winter-bash-2017

Winter has not come for me this year, it seems.

Last year, I was happy enough to get some hats, so I was naturally excited for this year also.

But, I log in this morning, to find that I don't see any differences in my view of the web site, there's no winter dressing.

All I see is:
[image]

I see hats being awarded on my most used sites (Workplace for example) on the WinterBash 2107 leaderboards so I know the sites are enrolled.  I see that I have two hats awarded, but nothing appeared in my inbox to say I'd earned them.

I am in the UK. I cleared my cache and logged out/in.

I am using IE11 on Windows 7 (supported browser for my organisation), and I have Active Scripting enabled in the security options.
I see snowflakes in FireFox.
I see snowflakes if I access the full site in Safari on my iPhone.

However, snowflakes **do** appear if I set the useragent to Firefox

[image]

Comment: You see the snowflake in other sites? You have any errors in your browser's console? Maybe you clicked "I hate hats" by mistake on one of the sites?

Comment: I see no snowlfakes anywhere.  And I wouldn't hit the "I hate hats", unless by complete accident.

Comment: I see snowflakes in Firefox, so this can't be a SE server side setting for me.  I'll clear even more cookies in IE and see if that sorts it out.

Comment: IE is probably not supported, especially if you're using old version, e.g. IE8 or IE9. You can also use Chrome, it's a modern browser which works just fine, and supports javascript, which is required.

Comment: IE11 seemed fine last year....  And I just checked that I have Active Script enabled in IE11.

Comment: No no, it's not just the JS support. IE is full with security bugs, it does not follow any standards, and many more reasons why it should never be used. That's out of scope here, but the answer proves SE shares this opinion as well.

Comment: Maybe this fact would need to be added to the Winterbash FAQ, unless I'm the only one stupid enough to use IE11.

Comment: That would make a good feature request, yeah. (From quick search, looks like 3.33% of the people use IE11 which means not only you. :))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<strike>Winter Bash is disabled in IE. You'd only see black hats anyway: [Hats black in IE 11](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340293/hats-black-in-ie-11)</strike>

I have no idea what changed, but I can no longer reproduce this issue in IE. And this matches reports from other users who say that everything seems fine. So I have re-enabled Winter Bash in IE for the time being; I'm curious if other people are going to see broken hats.

Comment: Good decision. What about Edge? Also disabled/black?

Comment: No, Edge is fine.

Comment: Sigh.  But it would be good to have this fact stated in the FAQ.

Comment: Dear @balpha, let's do it right and... please remove IE 11 from officially supported platforms in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208

Comment: @Cœur At this time, we support IE11. As in: You can use IE11 to for questions and answers. But for fun stuff like hats, we're not going to spend time on making that work in a browser from 2014.

Comment: To avoid confusion, you should tell IE users that Winter Bash doesn't work in their browser. For example enable the snowflake in the top bar and when a user clicks on it show a message like "your browser doesn't support Winter Bash".

Comment: Why? I mean if you set the IE11 useragent to Firefox from the F12 tools, winter bash shows up, and **works perfectly**. Hats all appear and render correctly, changing hats works, positioning of hats works. Why shun a browser with 13% of the worlds browser share, the same amount as use Firefox, and 10% more than the number using Edge, when it works fine.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Interesting that you say that. The reason is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340293/hats-black-in-ie-11, and I reproduced that in IE11 (and it's a well-known IE issue), so it's surprising that you say it doesn't happen for you. I wouldn't disable it if it *worked*; I disabled it to not annoy people with broken hats who are already punished by being stuck on that old of a browser.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Oh and I don't know where your usage stats come from, but our numbers look vastly different. IE is an also-ran in Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange usage.

Comment: @balpha The [winterbash FAQ](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/faq) was the first place I looked when hat-day arrived.  I didn't see any mention of non-supported browsers there.  Tom's metric comes from [Netmarketshare](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx)

Comment: @balpha Note the comments in your linked question above (from last year).  The bug **only** affects IE11 on **Windows 10**.  For the sake of one platform combination, you're killing support on one browser.

Comment: @TomCarpenter See my update ^.

Comment: @Snow See above.

Comment: @balpha Yep.  Saw your edit a few minutes ago.  I can confirm that hats look fine to me in unadulterated IE11 on Win 7.  Many thanks for revisiting and resolving this one!

Comment: Woop :) Thank you @balpha.